# Splitting up stacks for assembly

Tags: the-secret-world

I frequently find myself shift-clicking stacks of an item to split up the stack, ready for assembly.

This can get quite time consuming when making multiple items so I was wondering if there was another method of splitting up stacks quickly?

[image: Assembly screen]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**There is!**

Simply **Left Click** the stack you want to split to pick it up, and then **right click** the bank slot, inventory slot, or assembly slot, in which you want to drop *one* of the item in question.

When you're finished, simply **left click** the inventory slot you'd like to place the remainder of the stack.

<sub>Alternately, in the specific case of assembly, you can drop the entire remaining stack on the last slot of the assembly window. Assembling your item will only use one item from the stack, and you can simply use the 'quick return' button to return the stack to your inventory.</sub>

Comment: Awesome! If you right click on an inventory/assembly square that already has an item of that type in it does this result in a new stack being created? IE: can you spam right click to move 8 of an item to another storage space?

Comment: No. It creates a new stack of one in the first availiable slot. To create stacks of a specific size, you'll still want to shift-click and use the slider/numeric entry.

Comment: Basically, it works mostly like Minecraft (except for splitting stacks into arbitrary sizes but how often do you really do that).

Comment: @Shinrai I split stacks into arbitrary sizes *very very often*.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - I can't remember the last time I did.  Different playstyles, I guess.  I like my stacks taking up the fewest slots possible.